# Как преобразовать структуру данных?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть фрейм данных как в пункте 1, нужно получить, как в пункте 2. Но есть нюанс, есть пустые значения, которые нельзя выбрасывать. Попробывала как в коде ниже. Все пустые значения были выброшены (то есть, по ним прошло суммирование а не надо было). Что делать?

```
df_new = df_new.set_index('Номер заявки').sum(level=0).stack()
```

Comment: Может быть стоит все пустые значения заполнить нулями и потом транспонировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.set_index("номер заявки").stack()
```